# Pattern Matching Python

Tags: python

I'm currently stuck on trying to make a naive algorithm which given a piece of a  pattern e.g aabba 
search for it in a text e.g abbbbaababaabbaaabbaa one letter at a time. It will compare a with the text if that is right then compares the next letter and if that's wrong the whole pattern will shift one and compare a with b etc

we were give code example

```
print "Input text: ",
text = raw_input()
print "Input pattern: ",
pattern = raw_input()

index = text.find(pattern)
while index > -1:
    print index
    index = text.find(pattern, index+1)
```

but the find() function in python is too fast(I need a non optimized sort of algorithm, using while
and for loops statements I guess).

Any help appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Is this homework? If so please tag it as such.

Comment: wait, wth does too fast mean?

Comment: It sounds like he's supposed to go through it character by character himself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess here's what you need, the following code does character-by-character comparison. You may also replace the calls to `find` by iterations over `text` which includes checks whether the first character of `text` matches the first character of `pattern`:

```
def my_find(text, pattern):
    '''Find the start index of a pattern string in a text.
    Return -1 if not found, and assume that pattern is not empty'''

    found = False
    current_start_index = text.find(pattern[0])
    index_text = current_start_index
    index_pattern = 0

    while not found and index_text + len(pattern) - 1 < len(text) and \
            current_start_index != -1:

        index_text += 1
        index_pattern += 1

        while index_text < len(text) and \
                index_pattern < len(pattern) and \
                text[index_text] == pattern[index_pattern]:

            if index_pattern == len(pattern) - 1:
                found = True
                break
            else:
                index_text += 1
                index_pattern += 1

        if not found:
            current_start_index = text.find(pattern[0],current_start_index + 1)
            index_text = current_start_index

    if found:
        return current_start_index
    else:
        -1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def my_find(haystack, needle):
    n_len = len(needle)
    start = 0
    while start <= (len(haystack)-n_len+1):
        if haystack[start:start+n_len-1] == needle:
            return True
        start += 1
```

This is, as far as I can understand, your algorithm. Not tested, will test and let you know if it works.

Tested and seems to work.

Comment: Just to point out, iterating over lists or arrays etc are about the worst thing you can do in python. The performance hit is significantly huge compared to C or C++. Also, you would want to use regular expressions do these types of matching to save yourself from bugs, off-by-one's etc....

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you are learning about regular expressions, here's a snippet that may help you get started.

```
myFileName = "abbababaaa"
patternToMatch = "ababa"

i = 0
j = 0
while (i < len(myFileName)):
    if (patternToMatch[i:i] == myFileName[j:j]):
        i++
        j++
    else:
        i = 0        

if len(patternToMatch) == i:
    # matched a pattern
```

Comment: -1 He supposed to go through it char by char its in the homework tag

Comment: Notice the title.... Pattern Matching Python. This would indicate a regular expression would be acceptable. You can certainly match single chars with a regex. But, if you are going to iterate over arrays or strings then use C or C++

Comment: If you read the question, it says that he wants to do it character by charcter, and that's not what the regex is doing, its just finding the results, and he's not really writing an "algorithm"

Comment: You could do this just as easily in C++ using substr

Comment: I'm afraid he would like to use python.